# Variable Groups and multiline strings

Tags: azure-devops

Is there a way to use a multiline string/scaler with an Azure DevOps Variable group? Below is the YAML I'd like to store in a Variable Group.

variables:

- name: emailList
  value: |
  email1
  email2
  email3

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a multiline string/scaler with an Azure DevOps Variable group. However, on my tests, multiline variables in Azure DevOps Variable group may not be supported at the moment.